# File.WriteAllText and File.Copy issue

Tags: c#

I am creating a file using `File.WriteAllText` and copying the same file to another directory using `File.Copy` method. But for some reason it doesn't create a file in the source directory but it does copy it to destination directory.

What could be the problem? Please let me know.

```
File.WriteAllText(sourceFilePath, Contents.ToString());
File.Copy(sourceFilePath, destFilePath);
```

Comment: Is this behavior consistent with other paths?

Answer (score 7):

Well, you know for a fact that the file actually did get created, otherwise File.Copy() throws an exception.  And File.Copy() never deletes the source file, like File.Move() does.

The simplest explanation is that the file is just getting created in a folder that you didn't expect.  Which is common if `sourceFilePath` is not an absolute path.  This commonly happens when you've used OpenFileDialog with its RestoreDirectory property set to false.  For example.

Avoid this by always using absolute paths.  Environment.GetFolderPath() is your friend.

Comment: It created a file this time but it's writing the old contents to the text file. File.Copy works fine with destinaton directory.

Comment: It is writing old contents?  Or are you looking at an old version of the file?  More evidence that it is creating the file in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are the method calls concurrent as per your example?

If so, you could call File.WriteAllText twice to circumvent the issue, though I don't know why it's occuring.

You could do a File.Exists check prior to the copy, or perhaps try a Thread.Sleep(100) and see it's a disk I/O type issue.

Answer (score 0):

What folder are you writing to?  Could this be a Vista/7 folder virtualization issue?

If you could show us the actual code you are using, it would be helpful.